# How can I create an event trace with logman.exe on W2K8?

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance-monitoring, windows-event-log, performance

For various reasons, I'd like to get a trace of disk accesses on some Windows Server 2008 machines.

I can set up a user defined data collector set in the Reliability and Performance Monitor tool to create an event trace using the "Windows Kernel Trace" provider ("disk" suboption), and this works fine.

However, I really would like to automate this using the logman.exe command.  The documentation on logman is, I'd say, sparse.  (If there's some great documentation out there, I'd be very grateful for a pointer!)  I've tried using both commands with the `-ets` option and without, and using both the `logman create trace <name> <params>`/`logman start <name>` and the `-ets`-only `logman start <name> <params> -ets` method.

Nothing I've tried seems to work:

```
C:\>mkdir \tracedata

C:\>logman create trace DiskTr1 -p "Windows Kernel Trace" disk -o "C:\tracedata\DiskTr1"
The command completed successfully.

C:\>logman start DiskTr1

Error:
The session name provided is invalid.

C:\>logman start DiskTr2 -p "Windows Kernel Trace" disk -o "C:\tracedata\DiskTr2" -ets

Error:
The session name provided is invalid.

C:\>logman create trace DiskTr3 -p "Windows Kernel Trace" disk -o "C:\tracedata\DiskTr3" -ets

Error:
The session name provided is invalid.
```

I've also tried variants using the GUID for the provider and a hex value for the `disk` suboption, and so far nothing seems to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The 'Windows Kernel Trace' provider is considered a special provider in ETW, and it will only log to a session called 'NT Kernel Logger'.

See http://www.daschmelzer.com/cmg2006/PDFs/096.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
logman start "NT Kernel Logger" -p "Windows Kernel Trace" (disk) -o events.etl -ets
```